# For in loop after pushing a array to object, consoling as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I am looping a object, when i loop the object, i am pushing a array. after i pushed the array in to object, when i console i am getting a result as undefined..  what is wrong here..

mycode:

```
 var mainLink = {"links":[]};

     for(key in obj){
                if(obj[key].hasOwnProperty("value")){
                    mainLink.links.push({"label" : key,"link" : obj[key]["MainLink"], "subLinks": [] });
                    console.log(mainLink.links.subLinks); // why i am getting undefined instead array?
                }else{
                    mainLink.links.push({"label" : key,"link" : obj[key]});
                }
            }
```

Instead of array i am just getting as undefined... what is wrong here..

Comment: I guess it will be better, if you can add this to a fiddle

Comment: Where have you defined `obj` , i guess it should be `mainLink` .

Comment: `subLinks` is a property of the item, not of the `links` array

Comment: maybe because you add nothing to sublinks `"subLinks": []` and then `mainLink.links.subLinks` returns an empty array

Comment: Always use console to debug it, you'd see what your issue is

Answer (score 3):

According to your code, `mainLink.links` is an array and `mainLink.links.subLinks` as such is indeed `undefined`.

Accessing it as `mainLink.links[0].subLinks` (replace `0` with appropriate index) should give you the expected result.

For example:

```
console.log(mainLink.links[mainLink.links.length-1].subLinks);
```